# Errors after updating phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, debian, phpmyadmin

After updating phpMyAdmin to v4.7.5 on my Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) I'm getting:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.  Or
>   alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

This is what's `not OK`:

https://image.ibb.co/jW3fOG/Bildschirmfoto_2017_11_14_um_17_18_34.png

I added the following in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
```

But after reboot it's still the same, still the same errors.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

Added the following lines to `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';` but maybe doesn't matter where in `config.inc.php`):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
```

Then I created a file called `import.sql` with the content from here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql

Then I `reboot`ed and ready!

The errors don't appear any more!

Comment: You've got the right idea, although there's no need to reboot after those steps. `create_tables.sql` is also included with the official phpMyAdmin download.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using the Debian packaged version, you should be able to sort it with `dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`.

The solution you used is what I'd normally suggest, but the Debian package should handle such things for you easier than doing it manually. Either solution should work fine for your purposes.